# Is it safer to have the salt in the source code?

Tags: passwords, password-storage

Is it safer to have the salt in the source code? If the db gets compromised with salts then everything is lost.. but if they only have hashes they can't do anything with it.. If the salt is in the source code, you could use their userid or something else? anyone know..﻿

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your question? Generally, you want each password to have unique salt. What do you mean by "compromised with salt"?

Comment: I want to know is it safer to store each password with a unique salt in the database or it is safer if I use the same salt for each password and have the salt hidden in the source code?

Comment: Then I'd say each password unique salt in db.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) - third paragraph: "A new salt is randomly generated for each password." There is a reason too for that, if you were interested a bit more into cryptography, try reading into rainbow tables.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I give you like over here in the comments :)

Comment: There you go, now you can like the answer if you want :)

Comment: I need 15 reputation first :(

Comment: Not for accepting answer as correct, if you wanted to do so. (So this question can then be marked as accepted)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew this feature even existed. I did it. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use new salt for each password and store them in the database alongside the passwords. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)#Common_mistakes for reasons. If you want to learn more about the topic, the whole wikipedia article is a great source, followed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table, maybe even some generic info about hashing like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function.